# Are there any drawbacks to mixing arrow functions in javascript classes?

Tags: javascript, class, lambda, arrow-functions

If you aren't familiar the EMCA6 Draft will be adding [arrow function syntax](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aarrow_function_syntax). The main differences being:

- Arrow functions have lexical this (so no need to call [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or create a closure)
- Shorter syntax `() => "foo"` vs `function(){ return "foo";}`
- Arrow functions lack a .prototype. So they cannot be used as constructors, cannot be called with new, and are meant to be lightweight.

With that being said, lets take a look at the following trivial example:

```
var Animal = function(sound) {
    this.sound = sound;
    //arrow notation has lexical this, so this makeNoise must be defined in the constructor
    Animal.prototype.makeNoise = () => this.sound;
};

let dog = new Animal("woof!");
dog.makeNoise(); //woof!
```

Here, I'm creating a simple class that just happens to use a arrow function as one of its methods rather than a normal function. I know this is setting the `Animal.prototype.makeNoise` every time we initialize an Animal, but does the above have any other drawbacks compared to the normal:

```
var Animal = function(sound) {
    this.sound = sound;
};
Animal.prototype.makeNoise = function() { return this.sound; };

let dog = new Animal("woof!");
dog.makeNoise(); //woof!
```

I'm curious to see if there any lurking dangers to doing this, as I'm sure people will be tempted to use the new shortened syntax anywhere they can get away with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well there's a new function object for each instantiation.

Comment: `function Animal(name, sound) { .. () => name + " says " + this.sound }` .. seems problematic with accidentally mixing due to assigning a prototype in the constructor ..?

Comment: @user2246674 you're right, declaring the function in the constructor also creates another closure so you have access to any parameters that are passed in or variables created in the Animal constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest against doing this, partly for the reason Pointy gave in his comment: you're creating a new arrow function object for every instance of Animal, which is bad for performance and terrible for memory management. It's actually even worse than just duplicating function objects: since it also creates a new closure around that function, the garbage collector will not be able to free any of your constructor's local variables as long as the animal object is still in memory.

But also because ECMAScript 6 also introduces a much better syntax for that exact purpose:

```
class Animal {
   constructor(sound) {
       this.sound = sound;
   }
   makeNoise() {
       return this.sound;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I know it's a bad idea in general, but was wondering if there was anything else that was particularly disastrous with it. It's also good to know that the new class syntax made it into EMCA6 draft, for some reason I thought it was still being proposed.

Comment: I edited the comment with about another bad consequence of using closure functions: it prevents garbage collection of your constructor's local variables.